# Error while opening new terminal tab: ptsname_r failed: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, fedora

I am trying to open a new terminal tab, but every time I try it I get this error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
ptsname_r failed: No such file or directory
```

Do you have an idea as for why this is happening? It started all of a sudden.
I am running MATE desktop on Fedora 23.

TIA!

Comment: OK, so I see that the devpts file system is not mounted. I issued the command `mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts` but I only got 0,2,pmts in my /dev/pts directory (so "1" is missing). How to fix this?

Comment: Adding the line `devpts           /dev/pts              devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0` to my fstab file made the trick.